# Authenticate new user through existing connection pool + mongo java driver + spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mongo-java-driver

My application is in spring boot using mongo-java-driver v3.2.2. I have multi tenancy implemented. Each tenant has single user for authentication. I am able to authenticate the user on application startup.

But I am unable to authenticate the new user on runtime by using same connection pool created by mongo client i.e. singleton in application.

Comment: What you mean by unable to authenticate ? In general you have mongo client created once. Then run time you get db/collection and run operations over that. Can you provide more information how you are authenticating.

Comment: yes i have one mongo client in application that authenticate the users according with db they belong by opening connection in connection pool. Lets consider one user per db. Authentication is done only once when we start the application or when we create mongo client. In my use case,  mongoclient is created and multiple users are authenticated with their respective db they belong, now i am creating one more db on same server and i am creating one user for that new db. Now, this user should be authenticate with same connections available in connection pool.